# c++ vector avoid reallocation by using .push_back or .resize()

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, stl

I have a question related to vector especially the option .push_back() and .resize(). 
When using this option c++(STL) will always reallocate every element when the current vector capacity is overstep. This is a problem for me, because I do have a vector of struct objects.

```
std::vector<node> v;
```

My struct is looking like this and keeps pointer to other elements of the vector

```
struct node
{
    std::array<node*, nrOfNeigh> neighb;
    node* parentNode; 
    double density;
    ...
}
```

Because my struct do have pointer to other elements of the vector, always when using .push_back() this dependency will not be valid anymore.

Do any of you have an idea to avoid this? 
I do not expect that there is a way to force std::vector not to reallocate.
I already tried to use .reserve() and thereby reserved as much is possible. this is possible but from the memory management point of view not nice.

Comment: Do you have to use `std::vector`?

Comment: Well, what else is it supposed to do when you call `push_back` and there isn't any capacity left?

Comment: You can reserve maximum place for your vector by `reserve()` function. You can give maximum capacity of your vector

Comment: Why do you need a *pointer* to an element in an array? Why not just maintain the *index*?

Comment: @chrisaycock So it can also point to things not in that vector? But yeah, a lot of time that capability isn't needed and it would probably the first solution I'd try.

Comment: 1) I do not have to use vector. I just need the possibility to add and delete elements. <br> 2)I am using a specific structure (octree). Therefore I need to save the pointer to the neighbour, which are elements of the same vector. 3) I tried to give maximum capacity by using .reserve(v.max_size()) but this did not worked. Therefore I defined it manual but the manual defined are much smaller than the actual one when using v.max_size().

Comment: @Sambo You haven't answered the question 'why do you need a pointer *instead of* an index'. If you use an index you can get the pointer whenever you need it, and the index will never be wrong even when the vector is reallocated. It does seem the obvious answer to your issue.

Comment: @John: Sorry, but I know what’s a pointer is and a reference but what’s an index? Sorry I am new in the world of c++

Comment: @Sambo An index is just an integer. If you have the index (called i say) then &neighb[i] is the pointer to the element at position i.

Comment: Ahh Ok, but this meens I always have to search for it inside the vector after using .bush_back(), right?

Comment: @Sambo: Yes, but since that `start_of_vector+index` code is so common, CPU's have optimized hardware for that.

Comment: I will try it, but an additional problem is that I am loosing my array information. Inside my node struct I always have some arrays. One of them keeps necessary X,Y,Z position information.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the node* fields in the struct only point to other 'node' objects in the vector, you can replace node* with an integral index into the vector.

Specifically,

```
struct node
{
    std::array<size_t, nrOfNeigh> neighb;
    size_t parentNodeId;
    double density;
    ...
}
```

Now, when you use push_back(), instead of storing &v.back(), you store 'v.size()-1'.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use a `std::vector<node *>` (or any of the countless smart pointer implementations in Boost), so you only reallocate the pointers to nodes, not the nodes themselves.

Don't forget to release the pointers if you're going the non-smart pointer route though.

Edit: *Especially* if you're holding entire arrays inside your struct. You don't want to go reallocating every fixed array every reallocation cycle. I would also not use fixed arrays, an inner `std::vector<node *>` to hold neighbours would scale better and avoid most of the buffer overflow problems software these days seems plagued with.

Comment: I also tried this one but this means I have to allocate dynamically every element (up to 20.000.000 and more) and this is pretty slow

Comment: I disagree with your evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use the `.reserve()` functionality of `vector` to allocate as much memory as you think you might need *before* you use the vector, thereby possibly avoiding the re-allocations. It can also speed up vector pushes in some instances. See [here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve)

Comment: I tried this one. Manually defining the max number is working fine. I am able to define about 2.000.000 but when using the .max_size() member function I actually should be able to define 6.945.456 elements.